# how to rotate the android widget text? and something I don't understand

Tags: android, textview, rotation

I am try to make the textbox/textview inside my android widget rotate, but i dont know how to.

Questions:

1. how to make the text inside rotate, like from left to right for widget?
   2.
2. remoteViews.setTextViewText how can this work with animation?

Here is the widget example code I played around and wanted to make the text rotate.

```
public class WatchWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{
@Override
public void onUpdate(   Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                        int[] appWidgetIds ) 
{
    DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance( SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault() );

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main );
    ComponentName watchWidget = new ComponentName( context, WatchWidget.class );    

    remoteViews.setTextViewText( R.id.widget_textview, "Time = " + format.format( new Date()));

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget( watchWidget, remoteViews );

}
}

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:layout_margin="8dip"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget_textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dip"
    android:layout_weight="16"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="8pt" />

</LinearLayout>
```